# Create website with HTML/CSS Front end work with Java backend

Tags: java, html, css, web-deployment, minecraft

I'm kind of stuck on a project i want to create, but i don't know anything about modern web development with full stack and all this other stuff. So because of this i have absolutely no clue on how to go about this. This is what i know and this is what i need to accomplish...

**What i know:**

- Create/Host a classic LAMP Server
- Manage LAMP Server
- Create HTML/CSS PAge with designer or handcode

**What i need to accomplish**

- Create website like TopG, where server owners can post their Minecraft Servers on a list
- Be able to create an account to manage their servers (I know this can be done in PHP so this is fine for now)
- Use a java library called Votifier.jar. This is used when a user votes for a server, the vote submitted is sent to the Minecraft Server via port 25565 and after that the Minecraft Server handles what happens with the vote. I need my front-end to interact with this jar file/library and send the vote information to the Minecraft Server the user voted for.

***This*** is the part where i have absolutely no clue on how to accomplish this task.

I thought that i may have to just code the entire back-end of my website using Java instead of PHP, so i encountered [Spring](https://spring.io/) and tried to learn how to use it but i then was unsure how on earth to get Spring to work with the front-end HTML.

So at this point i don't know what to do or how to accomplish my goal... What i don't want to do is write the entire website with LAMP, then when the time comes to implement Votifier i end up having to rewrite the entire website in some other framework because of this jar file...

How do i go about this?

Must i use a Java backend? or can i stick with what i know which is classic LAMP?

Let me know if you need more clarification. I'll leave examples of existing websites so you can kind of get the feel of what i need to do.

https://minecraft-mp.com/server-s252794

If you click on the vote button, it takes you to another page where you enter your Minecraft username, solve the captcha and then it submits the vote and sends the vote info using Votifier to the Minecraft server, and from there the website's job is done...

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at Spring thymeleaf or you can run an additional frontend client that runs in parallel with the spring restfull api such as react or angular

Comment: Unless you have time to learn Spring framework, I think you should take a look on pure JSP first.

Answer (score 2):

There's no requisite to use Java for your backend, voting sites don't utilize any special Minecraft APIs. Rather, many of the major lists support common bukkit/spigot APIs (e.g. Votifier/NuVotifier/etc). These APIs make use of PKI authentication, using either RSA keys or just a simple string secret. Your service needs to be able to have accounts, a server listing (with posts), and a way for that user to set up their server posting with their server.

For this part, you need to verify ownership of the server (fake postings), and then exchange keys for the Votifier api. NuVotifier allows adding a server list site's public key instead of the other way around it looks like, but that's up to you.

All of this can be accomplished in whatever web/backend language and data engine you are comfortable with.

Comment: after i calmed down i looked at NuVotifier's Wiki/GitHub page and they actually have PHP code i can use to accomplish what i was stuck on. - https://github.com/NuVotifier/votifier2-php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at JSP([JavaServer Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages))? is java based, similar to php.

You can crate dynamically generated web pages, using html, xml and java.

i've used it a few weeks ago, for simple project, is realy easy to work with, if you know how to program with java will be a lot easier.

I'm not a web developer so a can't help you much more than this, but maybe it gives you a place to start.

i sugest you to seek for mor info before start you project.

Comment: I actually do know how to code in Java as ive had to get back into it to code plugins for my own minecraft server. I also came across another question mentioning JSP but they said it was not recommended?

Comment: checkout thymeleaf, probably the best templating engine to use with java spring IMO